# Mining with a geforce 315

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-hardware

I have a simple computer: 4GB ram, Intel core 2 duo E4500 and a Geforce 315 (i also have a Geforce 9400 but I don't know which is better) and I was wondering if it would be possible (without overheating my PC) to mine bitcoin with it. I dont care much about the electricity bill because i just want to do it for a hobby but if someone could let me know that would be great.

Cheers,

Ash

Comment: You'll be getting 0.000 bitcoin. You'll be wearing out the fans on your GPUs and elsewhere for no reward.

Comment: Not only is it not worth it (even assuming zero-cost for electricity), it simply won't work.  You'll likely die of old age before earning anything.  Bitcoin is a booming ecosystem for those with technical skills, so your time is almost certainly better spent doing something else as a hobby.

Answer (score 0):

Just to discourage you further:

1. You'll have a very difficult time finding a mining client that will run GPUs at this point. You'll most likely have to compile it yourself.
2. Even with the [best possible graphics card](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Non-specialized_hardware_comparison), it'll take you around 10,000 YEARS to find a POW-hash given the current difficulty.
3. You'll be making about 0.36 cents per day at the current bitcoin price with this amazing rig. Your card gets about 1/100th of that, so it'd be 0.004 cents a day, or a whole year to earn about 1.5 cents.

The wear on tear on your machine is insanely expensive compared to that.

If you're interested in making bitcoins with your machine, I would suggest you create an API service of some kind using 21.co's [API](https://21.co/learn/).